# sap.ui.commons.Link doesn't work in Binding

Tags: sapui5

I have a table when I try to bind the column of this table to a json data. It works in one of my tables and in other tables it doesn't show anything. I checked content and the way I get the json data and it is exactly the same in all tables.

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Names"}), 
            template: 
                new sap.ui.commons.Link({
                text:"{name}",
                })
                }));
```

the table that shows the content sits in shell and other tables that show nothing sit inside sap.ui.ux3.ThingGroup. I am wondering if the reason that I don't see the binding is because of ThingGroup or not? because as soon as I change the sap.ui.commons.Link to sap.ui.commons.TextView it works.

The cut down version of my code is:

```
addLayerTable: function(){
    var jsonData1 = {
            "layers" : []
    };
    $.getJSON(URI, {}).done(function(data) {
        if(data.layers !== undefined){
            $.each(data.layers, function(i, field) {
                jsonData1.layers.push({
                    "name" : field
                });
            });
        }
        layerDetailPage(jsonData1);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Error while reading layers Data or layers do not exist");
    });

    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
        rows:{
            path:"/layers",
        },
         width: "900px",
         visibleRowCount: 10,
         navigationMode : sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator
    });  
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Names"}), 
        template:
            new sap.ui.commons.Label({
            text:"{name}"
            }) 
            }));
    function layerDetailPage(layerData){
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData(layerData);
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "layerModel");
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
    };
    var oFC1 = new sap.ui.ux3.ThingGroup();
    oFC1.addContent(oTable);
    return oFC1;
}
```

As soon as I change the sap.ui.commons.Label to TextView, names become visible. but at the moment nothing. Funny enough if I add a press function to my table and try to get the name of the row in the table it works although it is not visible.

Comment: Do you see a `text` content of the Link without databinding, e.g. `text : "test"`

Comment: Yes i do Tim. If i hard code something it'll be there. If i use textview instead of link, itll be there as well. It is only the link that is not visible.

Comment: Ok, just for testing: Could you add a formatter function to the text property and see if it gets called at all? By the way, what UI5 version are you using? (Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S in your application)

Comment: Tim.This is the version number that I use:
1.20.6 (built at 201405261512, last change d8656b723f161379ea5b425bcc339b7dbb3578b7)

can you please help me to add formatter function to my code. I dont know how.

Thank you

Comment: Inside a ThingGroup should be fine, I've just tested it explicitly in a jsbin (jsbin.com/vaceh/1/edit - look for comments starting "// DJA") Can you show us a cut-down version of your complete code?

Comment: qmacro. I had a look at your code. I think your case is different to mine. I n your case there is a Link inside the ThingGroup. In my case there is a Link inside a table inside a ThingGroup.

Comment: To add a formatter function you replace `text : "{name}"` with  `text : {path: "name", formatter: function(value) {alert(value);  return value;}}` Let´s see if it gets called at all.

Comment: I have tried that @TimGerlach and it works. It returns null value around 10 times and then in the end it  returns the right value and still table doesn't show anything. As I said I have a function in the table which gets called when the table row is pressed, and when I click on the row it does work and return the value as well.

Comment: if your case is different to mine, why don't you try to take my example and add the table in between the ThingGroup and the Link?